# How install bumblebee with nvidia-390 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

i try to install bumblebee on my laptop

```
sudo apt install bumblebee linux-headers-generic
```

But i got following error

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bumblebee : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18)
             Recommends: virtualgl but it is not installable or
                         primus but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**How i can fix that ?**

My Env:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 4.18.0-16-generic 
Host: HP Spectre x360 Convertible 15-bl1XX 
GPU1: Intel UHD Graphics 620
GPU2: NVIDIA GeForce MX150
```

apt list --installed | grep nvidia

```
libnvidia-cfg1-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-390/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security,bionic,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-390/bionic,now 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-compute-utils-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-dkms-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-common-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 0.8.8.2 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/bionic,now 418.43-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390/bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic,now 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my terminal I typed `xserver-xorg-core` and found that xserver-xorg-core wasn't installed. So, `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core` should do it.

Comment: But it told you `bumblebee : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18)` that `bumblebee` depends on (requires) `xserver-xorg-core`, version 2:1.18 or later.

Comment: I'm a noob and just figuring this stuff out. Now I know

Comment: well, this probably means that you have `hwe` installed. Once you try to install `xserver-xorg-core ` it will remove your `hwe` related packages. Not sure that's what you looking for...